# is there a way to add the post URL to the results of fselect facet in Facetwp plugin?

Tags: permalinks, filters

I am using fselect (autocomplete search) Facet which is a facet type of the FacetWP plugin to show the titles of a custom post type as a result. 
what i want to do is to redirect the user to the selected post.

Is there a way to add the post url to the output HTML of the result ?

i have tried to use facetwp_facet_html and facetwp_index_row filters but got no result.

Comment: Maybe you try it [here](https://facetwp.com/documentation/) on the 3rd party website. Asking support for a 3rd party plugin should be done at their forums/blogs/websites/email.